# Rotate DIV element

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

how rotate div element in TCPDF with xhtml or html

test with rotate css3 no work

i need help, css3 working in last version TCPDF?

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
writing-mode: lr-tb;
```

Answer (score 2):

TCPDF has a good XHTML+CSS sample [sample](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.phps) I've changed it a bit.

```
// define some HTML content with style
$html = <<<EOF
    <style>
    ...
        div.test {
            color: #CC0000;
            background-color: #FFFF66;
            font-family: helvetica;
            font-size: 10pt;
            border-style: solid solid solid solid;
            border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
            border-color: green #FF00FF blue red;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
        }
    </style>
    <div class="test">example of rotated DIV with border and fill.<br />Some text.</div>
EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('RotatedDIV_Sample.pdf', 'I');
```